# Can the modifier form ( な/い) of an adjective follow the subject marker when there is no noun to modify?

Tags: word-order

In this phrase '天気が好きなんです' 好きな follows the subject marker. Is this because the phrase ends with んです?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. A predicate normally comes after a subject. Do you understand what a predicate is? In 春が来た ("Spring came"), 来た is the predicate, and this has little to do with んです.

Comment: I see that my question was wrong. I have changed it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [を vs が with use against 好き?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/%e3%82%92-vs-%e3%81%8c-with-use-against-%e5%a5%bd%e3%81%8d)

Comment: I don't think so.  It doesn't include 好きな or んです.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/52284/is-%e3%81%aa%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99-the-same-as-%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99 and also https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18408/problems-understanding-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%ae-in-this-sentence

Answer (score 4):

In 天気が好きなんです, "好きなんです" is the predicate. Subject + が + predicate is a common sentence pattern.

As for why 好きな follows 天気が, you cannot simply say 天気が好きな. First, at the most elementary level, you will have learned to use 天気が好きだ to mean "(I) like the weather." Here 好きだ is the predicate. You cannot say 天気が好きな because as a na-adjective, 好きな must be followed by a noun that it modifies.

Note that んです is not a fancy version of だ. んです arises as follows. First, 好きな modifies の, which is a 形式名詞. の here doesn't have an intrinsic meaning. It simply serves a syntactic purpose, allowing you to use an adjective where a noun is required. As a noun phrase, 好きなの cannot be a predicate; it must be followed by だ/です. So we have 天気が好きなのです. Informally, の can be replaced by ん and you have 天気が好きなんです.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen other similar questions where the response suggests that this is the attributive particleな, but I prefer your explanation that 好き must take the form 好きな when modifying (the explanatory) の.

Comment: "As a noun phrase, 好きなの cannot be a predicate; it must be followed by だ/です" this is not really accurate taking into account the frequency of casual speech with no copula. 好きなの has definitely been said by plenty of people, although it's fairly feminine.